# SQL Query for removing redundant data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data like:

[image]

```
ProductID   Language    Vendor  Title   ProductVersionID    Version ColloquialVersion   ProductEditionID
1   English Microsoft Corporation   SQL Server  1   13  NULL    NULL
1   English Microsoft Corporation   SQL Server  2   13.0.0  NULL    NULL
1   English Microsoft Corporation   SQL Server  3   13.0.0.0    NULL    NULL
1   English Microsoft Corporation   SQL Server  4   13.0.0.275  NULL    NULL
2   English Microsoft Corporation   Visual Studio   5   13  NULL    NULL
2   English Microsoft Corporation   Visual Studio   6   13.0.0  NULL    NULL
2   English Microsoft Corporation   Visual Studio   7   13.0.0.0    NULL    NULL
2   English Microsoft Corporation   Visual Studio   8   13.0.0.275  NULL    NULL
```

My question is:

I want to create queries to remove the redundant row having similar version version Example 13.0, 13.0.0, 13.0.0.0 is same for SQL Server. So i want to delete the rows of having version 13.0, 13.0.0, 13.0.0.0 and left only wid the version 13.0.0.275.

Is there any way to do the same using some SQL query.

Please help.

Comment: Please zoom image for more clear view of data

Comment: what is the datatype of version?

Comment: why 13.0.0275, what is the logic and also mysql or sqlserver syntax you want.

Comment: @Ajay2707: it seems clear that his logic defines two versions as identical if they only differ by one or more `.0` suffixes.  So 13, 13.0, 13.0.0 are all the same, while 13.0.0.275 is different.

Comment: actually I want more refined version out of less refined version. It want 13.0.0.0 should be there and 13.0,13.0.0 record should be deleted.

Comment: @mridul: The datatype of version is varchar

Answer (score 1):

There is some approaches to accomplish this. Try this :

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE (
    productid INT
    ,title VARCHAR(15)
    ,versionNo VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT INTO @t
VALUES (
    1
    ,'SQL Server'
    ,'13'
    )
    ,(
    1
    ,'SQL Server'
    ,'13.0.0'
    )
    ,(
    1
    ,'SQL Server'
    ,'13.0.0.0'
    )
    ,(
    1
    ,'SQL Server'
    ,'13.0.0.275'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'Visual Studio'
    ,'13'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'Visual Studio'
    ,'13.0.0'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'Visual Studio'
    ,'13.0.0.0'
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,'Visual Studio'
    ,'13.0.0.275'
    )

SELECT *
FROM @t

--1. Approach First
--delete t from @t t join
--(
--  select productid,title, max(versionNo) versionno from @t 
--  group by productid, title 
--) temp on t.productid = temp.productid and t.title = temp.title and t.versionno <> temp.versionno
--2. Approach Second
DELETE t
FROM @t t
JOIN
    --select distinct t. *  from @t t join
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT productid
        ,title
        ,S.a.value('(/H/r)[4]', 'VARCHAR(100)') FourthPostionValue
    FROM (
        SELECT *
            ,CAST(N'<H><r>' + Replace(versionno, '.', '</r><r>') + '</r></H>' AS XML) AS [vals]
        FROM @t
        ) d
    CROSS APPLY d.[vals].nodes('/H/r') S(a)
    ) TEMP ON t.productid = TEMP.productid
    AND t.title = TEMP.title --and isnull(temp.FourthPostionValue, 0) = 0 
    AND charindex(isnull(TEMP.FourthPostionValue, 2), t.versionNo) = 0

SELECT *
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 1):

Leveraging the fact that the `ProductVersionID` (per `ProductID`) seems to already agree to your conditions (assumption to be confirmed by looking at more data)

```
DELETE FROM table FROM table T1 
   WHERE ProductVersionID < 
     (SELECT max(ProductVersionID) 
         FROM table T2 WHERE T1.ProductID = T2.ProductID)
```

**EDIT**
This is the updated version after the new specification

```
DELETE FROM table 
FROM table T1 
WHERE T1.Version IN  
(
SELECT T1.Version
   FROM table T2 WHERE 
   ((
        (T2.Version = T1.Version+ '.0') 
        OR (T2.Version = T1.Version+ '.0.0')  
        OR (T2.Version = T1.Version+ '.0.0.0')
   )
   AND T2.ProductID = T1.ProductID )
```

Comment: Other answers directly use the string Version to find the max/latest release: that's not correct and you can read more about string sorting in SQL Server [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16958633/6298965). Anyway, in order to avoid needlessly complexity, I would advise to design the data structure with an appropriate int as version number equivalent

Comment: Scary how you think you know something, I was wrong, and I'm glad you pointed it out.

Comment: I do not think your solution is really that useful. Your choice would fold 13 into 13.0.0.275. It seems much more likely that the original poster wants 13, 13.0, 13.0.0 to be folded together but 13.0.0.275 to be kept separate. He made comments about an hour ago to this effect. The string Version is probably the *only* dependable data and it must be worked with. Sometimes you cannot "design the data structure" to your liking -- processing must take place somewhere, and if it can be readily done in SQL Server then why not.

Comment: @RossPresser The OP wrote "So i want to delete the rows of having version 13.0, 13.0.0, 13.0.0.0 and left only wid the version 13.0.0.275." Only a hour ago I see maybe the OP changed his mind... :-)

Comment: The data had a row for "13", no suffix ... he wanted that one retained, and the ones with zero suffixes removed.

Comment: @RossPresser Ok, but I'd say that the question was a bit unclear... would the only deletions occur for Versions ending with ".0" ? That would be even easier and it could be achieved in a similar way... What again looks wrong is using a max for the string field

Comment: Agreed, this question could definitely have been clearer, and max for the string field is definitely wrong.  I like the xml based string split solution, personally.

Comment: I agree with you, I also think that it is very interesting (but a bit complex and dbms-specific...)

Comment: As the version 13.0,13,13.0.0 and 13.0.0.0 is same is all sense... so i want to keep the more detailed version out of it that is 13.0.0.0 and delete rest version. But version 13.0.0.725 and 13.0.0.0 is different so I want to keep this record as it is. Another example is-- If there are versions like 2,2.0,2.1.0, then in this case, the record having version 2 and 2.0 is same so i want to keep the more detailed version of same version and delete rest. The record will show having version 2.0 and 2.1.0. How can dis is achieved?

Comment: @Niti I've changed the selection, according to your new specifications
Please, accept the edited answer, if this is what you asked for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you obtain the rows to delete with this select

```
    SELECT *
FROM my_table AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT vendor
        ,title
        ,max(Version) AS version
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY vendor
        ,title
    ) t ON t.vendor = a.vendor
    AND t.title = a.title
    AND t.version != a.version
```

and then

```
DELETE
FROM my_table AS a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT vendor
        ,title
        ,max(Version) AS version
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY vendor
        ,title
    ) t ON t.vendor = a.vendor
    AND t.title = a.title
    AND t.version != a.version
```

Comment: Also in this case, for example, version '13.11' would be alphabetically greater than version '13.101'

Comment: Well  expain me the exact rules you need

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    SELECT b.productid
    ,a.Title
    ,a.`Language`
    ,a.Vendor
    ,a.max_ver
FROM (
    SELECT max(Version) AS max_ver
        ,Title
        ,`Language`
        ,Vendor
        ,version
    FROM tbl_product
    GROUP BY `Language`
        ,Vendor
        ,Title
    ORDER BY Title
    ) AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT productid
        ,Title
        ,`Language`
        ,Vendor
        ,version
    FROM tbl_product
    ) AS b ON a.max_ver = b.version
    AND a.Title = b.Title;
```

good luck..

Answer (score 0):

OP is not being helpful by not being as clear or attempting to solve the problem with us.

However, **I will try once more:**

If in the column `Version` `'13.0.0.0'` and `'13.0.0.725'` are legitimate (or at least more official) versions of the product and all other records that do not match this pattern are to be removed...then use a LEN function. One scan, done.

```
 CREATE TABLE #tableA (
    productid INT
    ,title VARCHAR(15)
    , [Version] VARCHAR(50)
    )

INSERT INTO #tableA
VALUES (1,'SQL Server','13')
     , (1,'SQL Server','13.0.0')
     , (1,'SQL Server','13.0.0.0')
     , (1,'SQL Server','13.0.0.275')
     , (2,'Visual Studio','13')
     , (2,'Visual Studio','13.0.0')
     , (2,'Visual Studio','13.0.0.0')
     , (2,'Visual Studio','13.0.0.275')

SELECT  *
FROM #TableA
WHERE LEN( SUBSTRING(Version
                       , CHARINDEX('.', Version)
                       , LEN(Version) ) 
          )  < 6
```

The key here was determining the length you wanted. `'.0.0.0'` is 6 characters long. You can add special exceptions such as '13' if you wanted to just keep that.

The rest I leave up to you.

Comment: Note if it is possible for the version to be like '13.0.14.1' then you would necessarily need to adjust for this in the code.